# Unable to Edit "In-Mediation" file for SOAP Method in WSO2 API Manager version 4.0.0

Tags: rest, soap, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am unable to edit the "In-mediation" File present under WSO2 API Manager v4.0.0 > SOAP WSDL > API Configuration > Resources > Method name (E.g., POST /modifyClosureDataIO) > Mediation > In Tab EDIT.
I am able to edit the file and save it with customized changes, although when I refresh the page, all my changes are lost and the In mediation file goes back to its old state.
This is happening only in API Manager version 4.0.0.
I am able to do this in version 3.2.0
If there is any configuration where this can be changed, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you click save?

Comment: Yes, obviously :) @Pubci . It works on the older version 3.2.0 though. I'm just inquisitive if there is any configuration which we need to change so that the changes remain the same and don't get overwritten with kernel version.

Comment: Hi @Pubci, can you please help in giving some insights on the same? thanks.

Comment: [link] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/11508 - Public Git Issue raised for the same.

Comment: Fix is here -https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/10716/files